# Permission of sqlserver doesn't exist but with sa exists

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, sql-server-administration

I have a problem with sqlserver authentication .

When i connect to my instance using this information `local,windows authentican` i have this permission :

[image]

But with sqlserver authentication `local,sa,12345` i have this permission:

[image]

Last day the both permissions was same ,but today the permission of `windows authentication` are removed and i need the permission of `sqlauthentication`  in `windowsauthentication` how can i do that?

because my TFS use the windows authentication login .now my TFS doesn't work.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

> i need the permission of sqlauthentication in windowsauthentication how can i do that?

No, you don't. The reason that your sa account can see all of those other logins is because it is a system administrator (i.e. a member of the sysadmin server role). Whatever you're doing with TFS, I can almost guarantee that it doesn't need that level of permission. Find out what permissions you actually need ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253149.aspx) looks like a promising start) and grant those. Running any application with privileges it doesn't need is a bad idea in general.